# Mongoose Error while performing delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am running into following error but I unable to completely grasp the understanding behind the error.

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "XYZ" at path "_id" for model "Partner"
```

I have my schema defined as following

```
var partnerList = new Schema (
    {
        partnerName: String,
        supportedProducts: [String]
    },
    {
        collection: 'partnerList'
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Partner', partnerList);
```

The functionality of my delete function

```
delete: function (req, res) {
    var removePartner = req.params.partnerName;
    var promise = Partner.findByIdAndRemove(removePartner).exec();
    promise.then(function removePartner(val) {
        console.log('partner value removed');
        res.send(val);
    }).catch(function catchError(err){
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    });
}
```

I am trying to making a request to my node app service using 
**localhost:8443/data/XYZ**, where i am passing the value 'XYZ' as the parameter. This value is used to delete the appropriate object from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the error means that whatever you pass as your "XYZ" url param is not a valid [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

Guessing from your code you use the "partner name" (probably some arbitrary string) instead of the database id of the partner. However [`findByIdAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) requires you to specify an ObjectId as it uses this to identify which document to delete:

```
Model.findByIdAndRemove(id, [options], [callback])
```

Your delete API call could then look something like this: `http://localhost:8443/data/59558ccd7acc4dd63ea88988`. However for this the client needs to know the ObjectId of the partner.

So you have to either use the ObjectId of a partner in the URL, or use [`remove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove) to implement your custom delete query instead, for example like this (if name is the property you use to store your partner names):

```
Partner.remove({ name: partnerName }).exec();
```

**Be careful** however that this might remove multiple documents if your partner name is not unique, as remove will delete all documents matching the query.

In order to prevent this you can also use [`findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndRemove) using the same query. This would only remove one document at a time. If there are multiple partners with the same name it would remove the first one (depending on your sort order).

Comment: looks remove() should do the job in my case, but out of curiosity if i were to findOneAndRemove() how would i access the Objectid for that parameter value?

Comment: You would make your delete API call with the ObjectId in the URL instead of the partner name (XYZ). For example: http://localhost:8443/data/59558ccd7acc4dd63ea88988 -> See my updated answer.

Comment: Then I guess this is not very user friendly, as ObjectIds are really not made for humans ;) However normally you would not ask a user to enter anything in order to delete an item. He would just click on a link (e.g. delete) on an entry in a partner list or something and the application would then know and use the id to perform the delete. But as I don't know exactly what application you are building I can't tell whats best for your case.

Comment: ok that's tricky what if a client app is trying to connect to the service, the client will have no idea about the ObjectId

Comment: If the client doesn't know about the id then you really have no choice as to offer a delete by some identifier (e.g. the name) that the client knows about. However I would strongly recommend you to make sure that this key is then unique.

Comment: I hope this gives you some options and find a way! BTW: If you found my answer helped you solve your problem you can accept and optionally upvote it.

Comment: yes thanks for the help. I can't upvote yet, but i can accept the answer.